# How to translate Ἀγαθῶν ἓνεκα οὐ γίνεσθαι

Tags: ancient-greek, reference-request, greek-to-english-translation

How should the following (highlighted) quote of Socrates be translated?

[image]

Here's the relevant sentence:

> Thus Socrates said of the Civil law, Ἀγαθῶν ἓνεκα οὐ γίνεσθαι.

I came up with the following in my attempt at translating:

> Doing good for the sake of not becoming...

I'm mostly confused about how γίνεσθαι should be understood.

And it would also be great if someone could figure out where this quote comes from. It looks to me like the sort of thing Socrates spoke of in his conversation with Gorgias.

Comment: ἓνεκα is postpositive and belongs with ἀγαθῶν; if it were introducing a clause of purpose the οὐ would be μή. I don't think ἀγαθῶν is a form of ἀγαθόω, but just a genitive plural of ἀγαθός (governed by ἓνεκα).

Comment: @Cairnarvon - OK. That makes more sense. So it would mean something like [The civil law] does not arise on account of those that are good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [*Thesaurus Linguae Graecae*](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/), I was unable to find that sequence of words in Plato (or elsewhere). I'm also having trouble locating that exact thought in Plato.

The closest direct reference I could find is from [Clement of Alexandria's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clement_of_Alexandria) *Stromata* (AD ~200), 4.3.10, where he says:

> «δικαίῳ γὰρ οὐ κεῖται νόμος,» ἡ γραφή φησιν. καλῶς οὖν Ἡράκλειτος «δίκης ὄνομα» φησὶν «οὐκ ἂν ᾔδεσαν, εἰ ταῦτα μὴ ἦν,» Σωκράτης δὲ νόμον **ἕνεκα ἀγαθῶν οὐκ ἂν γενέσθαι**.

My quick translation (though I'm a little uncertain about the Heraclitus quote):

> Scripture says, "For the law is not laid down for the just man." So Heraclitus rightly said, "They would not know the name of 'right,' if these things did not exist [?]," and Socrates [rightly said] that the law **would not come to be for the sake of good men.**

Three small differences in the quote:

- As noted in the comments, *ἕνεκα* is usually postpositive but it can also precede its object. It is likely that the author (Burgesse) changed the order to the more usual postpositive.
- In addition, he switched the infinitive from aorist (γενέσθαι) to present (γί[γ]νεσθαι).
- The quote above uses ἄν, which I've translated above with "would."

I'd be interested to hear if anyone can locate a more proximate source for this quote than Clement. I'm sure the *thought* can be found somewhere in Plato, but the closeness of Clement's wording makes me suspect this is what Burgesse had under his eyes.

Comment: If it's Socrates, it might not have come from Plato, but a lost work of Xenophon or the other disciples whose works are no longer extant.